How to run triton ONNX models on CPU concurrently?
Description
I run multiple model instances on the CPU (onnx backend).
I'm confused about how to ensure parallelism in my Triton queries.
On the one hand, the number of model instances directly affects how many requests the server can process in parallel (link), but on the other hand, I don’t see any significant difference at all between how I call the model’s endpoint:

sequentially vs parallel
many instances vs one.

Triton Information
nvcr.io/nvidia/tritonserver:24.01-py3
Maybe I'm doing something wrong or maybe the problem is in the onnx backend, I'm not sure.
I'm running two identical models but with different numbers of instances.
model.onnx

config.pbtxt  (model_cpu_1)

platform: "onnxruntime_onnx"
max_batch_size: 16
input[
    {
        name: "input"
        data_type:  TYPE_FP32
        dims: [3, 1024, 1024]
    }
]
output:[
    {
        name: "logits"
        data_type:  TYPE_FP32
        dims: [1, 1024, 1024]
    }
]
dynamic_batching { }
instance_group {
  count: 1
  kind: KIND_CPU
}


config.pbtxt  (model_cpu_10)

platform: "onnxruntime_onnx"
max_batch_size: 16
input[
    {
        name: "input"
        data_type:  TYPE_FP32
        dims: [3, 1024, 1024]
    }
]
output:[
    {
        name: "logits"
        data_type:  TYPE_FP32
        dims: [1, 1024, 1024]
    }
]
dynamic_batching { }
instance_group {
  count: 10
  kind: KIND_CPU
}

client.py
from typing import List, Optional, Tuple
import numpy as np
import time
import tritonclient.http as httpclient
import asyncio


def call_seq(
    client, *, 
    model_name: str,
    input_shape: Tuple[int, int, int, int],
    n: int = 1,
):
    input_name = "input"
    output_name = "logits"
    input_data = httpclient.InferInput(input_name, input_shape, "FP32")
    input_data.set_data_from_numpy(np.random.randn(*input_shape).astype(np.float32))
    output_holder = httpclient.InferRequestedOutput(output_name)
    time_measurements = []
    
    for _ in range(n):
        start_time = time.time()
        reults = client.infer(
            model_name=model_name,
            inputs=[input_data],
            outputs=[output_holder],
        )
        time_measurements.append(time.time() - start_time)
    
    time_measurements = np.array(time_measurements)
    avg_time = time_measurements.mean()
    total_time = time_measurements.sum()
    
    print(f"Model: {model_name}, Mode: Sync\nInput Shape: {input_shape}, N: {n}") 
    print(f"Time:\n  AVG: {avg_time:0.4}s\n  Total: {total_time:0.4}s\n")


async def call_parallel(
    client, *, 
    model_name: str,
    input_shape: Tuple[int, int, int, int],
    n: int = 1,
):
    input_name = "input"
    output_name = "logits"
    input_data = httpclient.InferInput(input_name, input_shape, "FP32")
    input_data.set_data_from_numpy(np.random.randn(*input_shape).astype(np.float32))
    output_holder = httpclient.InferRequestedOutput(output_name)
    
    start_time = time.time()
    tasks = [
        _call_async(
            client,
            model_name,
            input_data,
            output_holder
        ) for _ in range(n)
    ]
    
    requests = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    for req in requests:
        results = req.get_result()
    total_time = time.time() - start_time
    avg_time = total_time / n
    
    print(f"Model: {model_name}, Mode: Async\nInput Shape: {input_shape}, N: {n}") 
    print(f"Time:\n  AVG: {avg_time:0.4}s\n  Total: {total_time:0.4}s\n")
    

async def _call_async(client, model_name, input_data, output_data):
    results = client.async_infer(
            model_name,
            inputs = [input_data],
            outputs = [output_data],
    )
    return results


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    triton_client = httpclient.InferenceServerClient(
        url='localhost:8000', 
        verbose=False
    )
    
    call_seq(
        triton_client,
        model_name="model_cpu_1",
        input_shape=(1, 3, 1024, 1024),
        n=50,
    )
    asyncio.run(call_parallel(
        triton_client,
        model_name="model_cpu_1",
        input_shape=(1, 3, 1024, 1024),
        n=50,
    ))
    
    call_seq(
        triton_client,
        model_name="model_cpu_10",
        input_shape=(1, 3, 1024, 1024),
        n=50,
    )
    asyncio.run(call_parallel(
        triton_client,
        model_name="model_cpu_10",
        input_shape=(1, 3, 1024, 1024),
        n=50,
    ))

I am getting such results:
Model: model_cpu_1, Mode: Sync
Input Shape: (1, 3, 1024, 1024), N: 50
Time:
  AVG: 0.1867s
  Total: 9.337s

Model: model_cpu_1, Mode: Async
Input Shape: (1, 3, 1024, 1024), N: 50
Time:
  AVG: 0.1924s
  Total: 9.621s

Model: model_cpu_10, Mode: Sync
Input Shape: (1, 3, 1024, 1024), N: 50
Time:
  AVG: 0.2031s
  Total: 10.15s

Model: model_cpu_10, Mode: Async
Input Shape: (1, 3, 1024, 1024), N: 50
Time:
  AVG: 0.2076s
  Total: 10.38s

Perf Analyzer results:
perf_analyzer -m model_cpu_1 -u localhost:8000 -i http --shape input:1,3,1024,1024 --concurrency-range 1:4 --async

Inferences/Second vs. Client Average Batch Latency
Concurrency: 1, throughput: 7.4433 infer/sec, latency 134196 usec
Concurrency: 2, throughput: 7.94337 infer/sec, latency 251028 usec
Concurrency: 3, throughput: 7.88775 infer/sec, latency 376430 usec
Concurrency: 4, throughput: 7.99904 infer/sec, latency 498129 usec

perf_analyzer -m model_cpu_1 -u localhost:8000 -i http --shape input:1,3,1024,1024 --concurrency-range 1:4 --sync

Inferences/Second vs. Client Average Batch Latency
Concurrency: 1, throughput: 7.49878 infer/sec, latency 132825 usec
Concurrency: 2, throughput: 7.99873 infer/sec, latency 249485 usec
Concurrency: 3, throughput: 7.88787 infer/sec, latency 375179 usec
Concurrency: 4, throughput: 8.10991 infer/sec, latency 492718 usec

perf_analyzer -m model_cpu_10 -u localhost:8000 -i http --shape input:1,3,1024,1024 --concurrency-range 1:4 --async

Inferences/Second vs. Client Average Batch Latency
Concurrency: 1, throughput: 6.55429 infer/sec, latency 153345 usec
Concurrency: 2, throughput: 7.83107 infer/sec, latency 252987 usec
Concurrency: 3, throughput: 5.05477 infer/sec, latency 601486 usec
Concurrency: 4, throughput: 4.10994 infer/sec, latency 952430 usec

perf_analyzer -m model_cpu_10 -u localhost:8000 -i http --shape input:1,3,1024,1024 --concurrency-range 1:4 --sync

Inferences/Second vs. Client Average Batch Latency
Concurrency: 1, throughput: 7.11005 infer/sec, latency 140678 usec
Concurrency: 2, throughput: 8.15793 infer/sec, latency 245401 usec
Concurrency: 3, throughput: 4.99932 infer/sec, latency 602047 usec
Concurrency: 4, throughput: 4.27726 infer/sec, latency 935371 usec

I'm curious why if on average the model completes tensor processing (1, 3, 1024, 1024) in about X seconds, then the total time of N requests is nowhere near X (even if N <= 10).
I understand that there may be other overhead costs, but the results seem counterintuitive to me.
I would appreciate any help.
Expected behavior
Let me illustrate with an example. If there are N instances (let N=10), and a request consisting of one sample takes X seconds (let X=1), then I expect that if we make N requests to N instances at the same time we will get approximately X seconds +/- overhead.
